# Vector2f to Vector2d explicit type conversion eigen

Tags: casting, type-conversion, typedef, eigen, eigen3

I am taking the return value of a function of return type Vector2f (Eigen library) into a variable. And then need to pass this variable into a function which requires 'Vector2d' datatype. How to go about the explicit conversion. Also Vector2f and Vector2d have been defined in project as 'Vec2f' and 'Vec2' using typedef. So please consider this while answering.

Answer (score 2):

An explicit cast is required for [Eigen objects](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a660200abaf1fc4b888330a37d6132b76). If you had (using your typedefs):

```
Vec2f originalMat(1.0f, 2.0f);
Vec2d castedMat = originalMat.cast<double>();
```

would give you a copy of the matrix, just with the `double` type.